# In Vue and Vue Router SPA, showing 404 for a not found resource

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, vue.js, vue-router

I'm using Vue and Vue Router in a SPA. In a view component I query a repository for a resource. If the resource is not found I want to show a 404 page whilst keeping the URL.

I.e. if I visit `/foo/non-existant-id` then a 404 page should be shown in place of the show page for the `foo` resource.

For clarity here is my router map:

```
router.map({
  '/foo/:id': {name: 'foo-show', component: FooShowPage},

  // Utilities
  '/': { name: 'home', component: HomePage },
  '*': { name: '404', component: NotFoundPage }
})
```

And in my `FooShowPage` I do the following:

```
ready () {
  // fetch the foo from the repo (app.foos)
  app.foos.fetchById(this.$route.params.id).then(foo => {
    this.foo = foo
  }).catch(e => {
    // foo is not found show a 404 page
    // using this.$route.router.go({name: '404'}) does not work as route is a wildcard 
    console.warn(e)
  })
}
```

Essentially it would probably involve replacing the `FooShowPage` in the router view with `NotFoundPage`, or redirecting to a defined 404 page whilst keeping the browser history untouched.

Comment: Did you solve this? I am currently looking into this and the provided answer doesnt work for me because I don't know which id is valid until I retrieve the result from the backend API

Comment: I have the same question but can't find a solution anywhere. I don't know if dynamic params are valid until I make an api call and receive a 404.

Answer (score 6):

You need to set a route for 404 page and then redirect unmatched routes to it. I use a `router.redirect` after the map to do such things.

```
router.map({
  '/': { name: 'home', component: HomePage },
  '/foo/:id': {name: 'foo-show', component: FooShowPage},
  '/404': {name: 'not-found', component: NotFound}
})

router.redirect({
    '*': '/404'
})
```

All routes that are NOT listed in the map will then be redirected to `/404`

Comment: best answer yet, but if i get something like /foo/:gibberish it doesn't trigger. Has to be managed in every route insides? Like an application logic issue? I miss my php

Comment: @Cristo use navigation guards to handle the redirection.

Answer (score 1):

Found a [solution at Vue.js forum](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/best-practice-to-redirect-to-404-a-dynamic-route/35445/3) — use [navigation guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard):

```
import store from '../store'

{
  path: '/lavori/:lavoro',
  name: 'lavoro',
  component: Lavoro,
  beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
    function isValid (id) {
      return store.getters.resourceByID(id) !== undefined
    }

    if (!isValid(to.params.id)) {
      next({ name: 'not-found' });
    }    
    next();
  }
},
```

Edit1: need to `import store` to get access to getters, from this [Github issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex-router-sync/issues/26) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42579601/how-to-access-async-store-data-in-vue-router-for-usage-in-beforeenter-hook)

Still a question how to leave same (requested) URL

Answer (score -1):

The best I've figured out how to do is to use a global interceptor with Axios to redirect all 404 responses received through the API the 404 route. However that does change the url to /404 like @Leo's answer.

```
const http = axios.create({
  headers: {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
  }
});

// Add some global response intercepters
http.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
  // For successes just continue as normal
  return response;

}, function (error) {
  // If we have a 404 redirect to the error page replacing the history
  if (error.response.status === 404) {
    return router.replace({ name: 'notfound' });
  }

  return Promise.reject(error);
});

export default http;
```