# How to use vue-router to redirect to 404 page with invalid URL parameter

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I use vue-router to navigate the user pages by their user id.
And the router.js looks like as follows

```
export default new Router({ 
  mode: 'history', 
  base: process.env.BASE_URL, 
  routes: [ 
    { 
      path: '/user/:id',
      name: 'user',  
      component: () =>  
        import(/* webpackChunkName: "user" */ './views/User.vue'),
      props: true               
    },
    {
      path: '/404', 
      name: '404',
      component: () => import('./views/404.vue'),
    },
  ] 
})
```

If someone go to the URL of `/user/some-invalid-id`, how do I redirect it to the 404 page?

In my app, all user data is loaded at the App.js' `breforecreate()`, and internally the User view is accessed as follows for existing users

```
<router-link :to="{name: 'user', params:{id: u.pk}}" >                  
  <a> {{u.first_name}} {{u.last_name}} </a>                             
</router-link>
```

I know it's possible to redirect programmatically with a push function call. But I don't know where this code should be used.

```
this.$router.push('/404')
```

In the `User.vue` view page, I use a vuex getter called `userByID` to retrieve data.

```
userByID: (state) => id => {
    return state.users.find(u => (u.pk == id))
}
```

Should `router.push('/404')` happen in `userByID` or its caller? How do we deal with the template rendering with `undefined` user object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use 'Navigation Guards`, specifically a `beforeEnter` hook in your `/user/:id` route.

Something sort of like this (not tested; just directional):

```
routes: [ 
    { 
        path: '/user/:id',
        name: 'user',  
        component: () =>  
            import(/* webpackChunkName: "user" */ './views/User.vue'),
        props: true,               
        beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
            if (!userById($route.params.id)) {
                next('/404'); 
            }
            else {
                next();
            }
        }        
  }
    },
    {
        path: '/404', 
        name: '404',
        component: () => import('./views/404.vue'),
    },
  ]
```

Note that you'll need to be able to determine if the user is valid without invoking the User.vue component.

You can also implement a `beforeRouteEnter` hook on User.vue directly, though you'll not be able to call other User.vue methods there as the component won't yet be mounted.

More on navigation guards:  https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-guards

Given your userById method is accessing the store, I found this post that might help you access the store in your `beforeEnter` method: [How to access async store data in vue-router for usage in beforeEnter hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42579601/how-to-access-async-store-data-in-vue-router-for-usage-in-beforeenter-hook)